# Multibib: How to override the default appearance of bibliography section headers

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

Using `multibib` (and `apacite`), if  I define two bibliographies entitled "Primary literature" and "Secondary Literature" by using the following lines:

```
\newcites{prim}{Primary Literature}
\newcites{sec}{Secondary Literature}
```

and then I write into the `document` block:

```
\section{Bibliography}
\nociteprim{ref1,ref2}
\bibliographystyleprim{apacite}
\bibliographyprim{publications}   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\section{Bibliography}
\nocitesec{ref3,ref4}
\bibliographystylesec{apacite}
\bibliographysec{publications}   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
```

then I obtain three sections, named "Bibliography", "Primary literature" and "Secondary Literature", respectively. However, I want to make "Primary literature" and "Secondary Literature" to appear with the style of `subsection` instead of `section` one.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the `natbib` package loaded as well?

Comment: No, should I load it?

Comment: Not necessarily. I asked because some of the `multibib` internals behave differently depending on whether or not `natbib` is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it you're using the document class `article` or one that's built on `article`. If that's not the case, please advise which document class you employ.

The following instructions may do what you want; place them in the preamble, after `multibib` has been loaded.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \let\origsection\section% save the original definition of \section
  \let\section\subsection%  make \section behave like \subsection
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \let\section\origsection% restore the original definition of \section
}
```

Here's the output of a complete MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{publications.bib}
@article{ref1,
  author = "A. Athor",
  title  = "Deep thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity",
  year   = 3001,
  volume = 1,
  pages  = 1,
}
@article{ref2,
  author = "B. Bthor",
  title  = "Deep thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity",
  year   = 3002,
  volume = 2,
  pages  = 1,
}
@article{ref3,
  author = "C. Cthor",
  title  = "Deep thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity",
  year   = 3003,
  volume = 3,
  pages  = 1,
}
@article{ref4,
  author = "D. Dthor",
  title  = "Deep thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity",
  year   = 3004,
  volume = 4,
  pages  = 1,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{apacite,multibib}
\newcites{prim}{Primary Literature}
\newcites{sec}{Secondary Literature}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \let\origsection\section% save original definition of \section
  \let\section\subsection%  make \section behave like \subsection
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \let\section\origsection% restore original definition of \section
}
\begin{document}
\nociteprim{ref1,ref2}
\nocitesec{ref3,ref4}

\section{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyleprim{apacite}
\bibliographyprim{publications} 

\bibliographystylesec{apacite}
\bibliographysec{publications}
\end{document}
```